# Time Constraint on this Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to put a time constrain on this query, but all my tries have failed :(
I want the time constrain from this date `2013-06-21 13:15:00.000` to `2013-06-28 13:15:00.000`.
These times are in a table called `trendLog15Min` in a column called `UTCTimeStamp`.

This is the query where I want the time constrain:

```
SELECT a.UTCTimeStamp, CASE WHEN a.ElapsedValue = b.ElapsedValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ConstantData
FROM tblLive_trendLog_15Min a,tblLive_trendLog_15Min b
WHERE a.UTCTimeStamp = dateadd(minute, -15, b.UTCTimeStamp)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to add `WHERE` criteria:

```
SELECT a.UTCTimeStamp, CASE WHEN a.ElapsedValue = b.ElapsedValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ConstantData 
FROM tblLive_trendLog_15Min a
    JOIN tblLive_trendLog_15Min b 
        ON a.UTCTimeStamp = dateadd(minute, -15, b.UTCTimeStamp)
WHERE a.UTCTimeStamp >= '2013-06-21 13:15:00.000' 
    AND a.UTCTimeStamp <= '2013-06-28 13:15:00.000'
```

Please note, I changed your query to use an `INNER JOIN`.

You can also use `BETWEEN` (although I prefer greater than/less than when working with dates):

```
WHERE a.UTCTimeStamp BETWEEN '2013-06-21 13:15:00.000' AND '2013-06-28 13:15:00.000'
```